# Flutter : How to center an icon next to hint text inside an input decoration?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, textfield

[Example of desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0rLL.png)

I have a `TextField` with an `InputDecoration` where I set a `hintText` and a `prefixIcon`, however the `prefixIcon` property that I am using will always pull the Icon all the way to the left.

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 30),
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
    hintText: 'Search',
    fillColor: Color(0xffF1F4FB),
    filled: true,
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Color(0xffF1F4FB),
      ),
    ),
    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Color(0xffF1F4FB),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I'm trying to change this to have the search icon and the hint text initially centered next to each other. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `IntrinsicWidth`.

With this solution, the search icon will be next to the `hinttext` and then it will stay next to the text input from the User.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 48.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 0.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber.shade300,
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.brown,
              width: 3.0,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: IntrinsicWidth(
              child: TextField(
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  hintText: 'Search',
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setting `prefixIcon` as a `Row` with MainAxisAlignment.center could do the trick. **but** it covers the whole textField, so we need to replace it with a normal icon when the textField is in focus.
You can detect focus using a [`FocusNode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html). To learn more read [Focus and text fields](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus)

Code:

```dart
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTextField({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTextFieldState createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // rebuild the textfield on focus changes
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 30),
        prefixIcon: !_focusNode.hasFocus && _controller.text.isEmpty
            ? Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.search),
                  Text('Search'),
                ],
              )
            : Icon(Icons.search),
        // hintText: 'Search',
        fillColor: Color(0xffF1F4FB),
        filled: true,
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xffF1F4FB),
          ),
        ),
        disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xffF1F4FB),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `prefixIconConstraints` to do that. Just add that to your `TextFormField`'s decoration with your `prefixIcon` like this:

```dart
prefixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(),
prefixIcon: Container(
   margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
   child: const Text('Rp'),
),
```

you should also want to make your field look bigger by adding some padding to `TextFormField`'s decoration:

```dart
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a solution.

[Official Flutter way](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42651#issuecomment-952629882)

using the `Align` widget. with `widthFactor` & `heightFactor`